# Facebook Graph API mutualfriends/ failing for my apps' access_token(s)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Note: similar to, but not a duplicate of [FB Graph API: Mutual Friends returns empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807266/fb-graph-api-mutual-friends-returns-empty-array), because OP there was successful in the API Explorer.

When I try the mutualfriends/ call in the API Explorer, for me and a friend of mine, with an Access Token generated by the "Get Access Token" button in the Explorer (and only user_friends checked), it works fine and it lists the info for our 7 mutual friends.

If I leave everything exactly the same, but then switch the access_token out with one from my app, suddenly it returns an empty list.  The access_token has user_friends enabled (don't all?).  I can use the access_token to make other calls successfully (such as to /friends), and the app is out of sandbox mode and lists as "Live".

What am I doing wrong?

Specific call being made in the explorer:

`${MYID}/mutualfriends?limit=5000&offset=0&user=${THEIRID}`

Answer (score 1):

It turned out what I thought was a user access_token was actually an app access_token, which just happened to work for every other call I was making from the app. For beginners like me: if two different users are given the same access token, you're doing it wrong.